# How do I give a task a property?

Tags: c#, task

I keep my tasks in a List and now I want to iterate over it and find out which of the tasks has "IsSpecial=true" set. 
But I can't find any way to actually create a property on a task *that is also modifyable by the task's action*.

```
class MyOwnTask: Task
{
    public bool IsSpecial= false;
}
new MyOwnTask(() => {
    this.IsSpecial = true; // "cannot use 'this' in static member"
});
```

passing an object state in doesn't work either because I can't query for it, so I'm out of ideas... doing this with threads would be easy so I dont know why this would be so impossible with tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous method used for the `Task`'s action uses the context of the code in which the anonymous method is declared, not the context of the `MyOwnTask` class. But that doesn't stop you from accessing members of `MyOwnTask`; you just need to use the correct object reference.

For example, this works fine:

```
MyOwnTask t = null;

t = new MyOwnTask(() => {
    t.IsSpecial = true;
});
```

This introduces the local variable `t`, which is captured by the anonymous method, and can be used to access the `IsSpecial` field.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, I had a brainfreeze and didn't realize that the `t` would be pretty much guaranteed to be non-null here always.